# Find the object that is farthest from the rest

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, spatial

The points are located all over the island, but there is clearly one point that is definitely the one I am looking for

I ran into a problem in Postgres when I was working with spatial dates. I have a table with columns: object id, latitude, longitude, and geometry. I need to find the object(point) that is farthest from the rest. How could I do that?

**Data**

```
CREATE TABLE cultural_sites
(
    cult_site_id text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    name text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    type_id integer,
    found_year integer,
    prot_cat_id integer,
    closest_house_id integer,
    lat double precision,
    "long" double precision,
    geom geometry(Point,4326),
    CONSTRAINT cult_site_id PRIMARY KEY (cult_site_id)
);

INSERT INTO cultural_sites(cult_site_id, lat, long)
VALUES (923048800130006, 46.152222, 33.7015), (911711012380005, 44.43722, 34.104166), (911711012630005, 44.42833, 34.1225), (911710892610005, 44.95, 34.097222), (911710892840005, 44.958084, 34.106479), (911710988820005, 44.947788, 34.099440), (911710988990005, 44.952224, 34.095908), (911710989390005, 44.9449409, 34.097), (911710989490005, 44.955555, 34.093888), (911710989510005, 44.946944, 34.1019444);

ALTER TABLE cultural_sites
ALTER COLUMN geom
type geometry(Point,4326) using st_point(long,lat);
```

[image]

Comment: Obviously, if the set just contains two points, then either both or nether is "farthest from the rest". One can picture larger collections of points with similar properties (e.g. all points equidistantly located around the circumference of a circle). Which is all to say - are you sure that such a unique point exists in your data set?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide the table structure, sample data and the expected results. Preferably within a fiddle.

Comment: @JimJones I updated the post. I am sorry if I misunderstood anything, my English is not that great

Comment: @VorobiovaKristina you have to post the data and table structure as SQL statements. We cannot copy&paste code from screenshots. Also, put it in a fiddle ;) here is an example for you to get started: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2006efff8083c30eeaabe8982f2b9b33

Comment: @JimJones Thank you! Here's the link: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=373ebe3f7557973d2af1c92ead1d4d94

Comment: @VorobiovaKristina nice. And you expect to get the cult_site_id: `923048800130006`, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a self join to calculate the distance of a reference point to the furthest point in the table, and in the outer query just filter it again with an `ORDER BY`  and `LIMIT` to get the longest distance:

```
SELECT t1.geom,t1.geom <-> j.geom AS distance
FROM cultural_sites t1
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT geom FROM cultural_sites t2    
  WHERE NOT t1.geom = t2.geom
  ORDER BY t1.geom <-> t2.geom
  LIMIT 1) j 
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 1;

                        geom                        |      distance      
----------------------------------------------------+--------------------
 0101000020E61000006F1283C0CAD94040A9DDAF027C134740 | 1.2593570786051942
```

[image]

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=940476e58403fe1af7216cd5f463cc01)